# Does space matters on a page for web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, web, performance-testing

My client complained me that my web page contains so many spaces so it is not good for the performance.

Does the space matters in web pages?

**UPDATE :**

I mean whitespace for performance and cost issue.

Comment: You mean... whitespace between elements in the HTML source?

Comment: The answer is no. Your client is focusing on the wrong thing. I'd ditch them and focus on getting clients that are more of a pleasure to work for. I'm positive this is just the tip of the iceberg. You can do yourself a favor and learn the technologies that you are using inside and out so that you can have confidence in these situations. Using stackoverflow is a good start.

Comment: @BrianWebster I do like the idea of picking nice clients, who are nice to work for, pay above the market rate, and pay ontime... Sadly, if I were able to pick my clients, I would have retired to a chateau in the South of France by now - Sometimes you just have to take the work and face the innane questions. My response is often "You hired me for my expertise right? If you know so much, surely you should just do this yourself?" ;)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you get those types of clients cushy, although I'm sure it's nice. I'm suggesting avoiding clients who argue with you about white space in HTML. They are clearly delusional. Yes, sometimes you have to work for them to pay the bills, but you'll grow your business and maintain sanity if you weed out those clients ASAP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, space, like any other character, has it's size. so, if you'll have a page full of spaces, then you'll pay the cost of transferring this additional bytes.
this can cost time, until the client receive the whole page, and money, if bandwidth is limited and you are charged for every byte.

there are tools that can automatically optimize your scripts and remove empty spaces and un-needed line breaks.

Comment: btw, could you tell me about those tools name ? Thanks again.

Comment: there are many modules doing this. try search for "html/javascript minify". here is a module does this: http://madskristensen.net/post/A-whitespace-removal-HTTP-module-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Reducing white space reduces also the size of your webpage in terms of bytes. Reducing the size of your webpage has positive results on the performance of your webpage.

Beware in some (old)browsers your result will change if you remove all the white space.

If you remove white space, the best you can do is do it at runtime with a module like this example:

[A whitespace removal HTTP module for ASP.NET 2.0](http://madskristensen.net/post/A-whitespace-removal-HTTP-module-for-ASPNET-20.aspx)

So you work environment is still readable.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, a text file with a single space comes in at 1byte.

A 1024 spaces, is 1kb, 1024bytes.

Either would be minimal to any kind of download speed and much greater optimisations can be had with just optimising a single Jpeg.

Search engines and Browers will ignore the white space, and therefore it will have minimal impact in the code.

**If** you have lots of white space in your actual page, then this can a good design element, or bad, all depending on your target audience etc... Either way, white space makes little difference IMHO.

***edit***

If you remove all your whitespace, make sure you keep a "normal" development copy, otherwise if you need to edit it you may struggle.

Generally, the "minifying" is performed on Scripts rather than HTML, but I can't see any reason why the same concept wouldn't work - it's just a case of diminishing gains.

If you spend 3 hours optimising the site to save 10kb vs. spending 3 hours creating better content, would your client be really happy?

Comment: Thanks for share the knowledge and asking me a good question !!

Comment: How do you get from 1000 spaces to 1.89kB ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman My mistake - just pasted the wrong number of times into Notepad++! As you can correctly infer, 1000 spaces, is 1000bytes!!! I'll edit to reflect the correct info!

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to optimise everything on a web page, however trivial, even whitespaces. But, it is painful to do it by hand. Use an automated process. You have not mentioned which server-side technology you are using. Depending on that each on has a different way of tackling this.

But, assuming for instance, you are using Apache, I would recommend installing the [mod_pagespeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod) from Google. Brilliant at optimising the page, not just whitepsaces.